# dll Export/init problem (static vars init?) Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, static-variables, dllexport

I want to run an example plugin for CLANG/LLVM. Specifically `llvm\tools\clang\examples\PrintFunctionNames`. I managed to build it and i see an `PrintFunctionNames.exports` but i dont think visual studios supports it. The file is simply `_ZN4llvm8Registry*`. I have no idea what that is but i suspect its namespace llvm, class Registry which is defined as

```
template <typename T, typename U = RegistryTraits<T> >
class Registry {
```

I suspect the key line is at the end of the example file

```
static FrontendPluginRegistry::Add<PrintFunctionNamesAction> X("print-fns", "print function names");
```

print-fns is the name while the 2nd param is the desc. When i try loading/running the dll via

```
clang -cc1 -load printFunctionNames.dll -plugin print-fns a.c
```

I get an error about not finding `print-fns`. I suspect its because the static variable is never being initialize thus it never registers the plugin. A wrong dll name would get an error loading module msg.

I created a def file and added it to my project. It compiled but still no luck. Here is my  def file

```
LIBRARY printFunctionNames
EXPORTS
X DATA
```

How do i register the plugin or get this example working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, becoming slightly more clear. To summarize: Visual Studio has nothing to do with it, really. This is a plugin for the clang executable. Therefore, there must be a method to communicate between them (the plugin interface). This appears to be an undocumented interface, so it's taking a bit off guesswork.

Troubleshooting DLL issues is done with "Dependency Walker" aka "Depends". It offers a profiling mode, in which all symbol lookups can be profiled. I.e. if you profile `clang -cc1 -load printFunctionNames.dll -plugin print-fns a.c`, you will see what symbols `clang` expects from your DLL, and in what order.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean. It loads it in dynamically, it doesnt really depend on it. I at least loaded it up and i didnt see anything helpful. I really think the problem is getting visual studios to initalize the static variable in my dll which registers the plugin. I looked at MSDN and saw it mention all exports must have library and i looked up how to export a variable (its through data). so i am quiet confused. Is there a way with depends to check what a dll expects DYNAMICALLY? I think i'll try my expeirment with the example that has main but is more different from what i want.

Comment: Static variables don't have to be exported; they're initialized as part of `DllMain()`. And yes, Dependency Walker's profiling mode is precisely want you want to check what an DLL _user_ expects dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to mix C++ code built with two different, incompatible compilers. That's not supported, and the error you're seeing is a typical sign of that: C++ compilers usually use a "name mangling scheme", and if two compilers are incompatible then their name mangling schemes don't line up. One compiler may mangle `llvm::Registry` as `_ZN4llvm8Registry*` while another refers to it as `llvm__Registry`.

Comment: Actually i built them using visual studios. That example i suspect is gcc. However the question is about getting the plugin to register (under VS) which it isnt doing